# /(userid)/likes/(pageid) returns incomplete results

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to accomplish the following: On a homepage of a customer (a Facebook app), after the user has logged in with Facebook, there should be an overlay, but only if the user has not "liked" the customer's Facebook page (which is *different from the app that I'm creating*). On this overlay, there should be a like button for the customers Facebook page.

I figued I could do this with the graph api, accessing `/(userid)/likes/(pageid)`. However, I recieve an empty result, even though I "like" the page.

If I access `/(userid)/likes`, I get only two results. These two are pages that I "liked", but those two do not show up in my facebook account under "other likes". The pages under "other likes" (the customers page is one of them) however do not show up in the result of the api call.

The funny thing is, I get always get these two pages in the result, regardless if I added the **"user_likes" permission**. I double checked with calling `/(userid)/permissions`, and the permissions settings are recognized correctly.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the permission "user_likes", then you could do something like the following in FQL:

```
select uid, page_id from page_fan where uid=me() and page_id={YOUR_PAGE_ID}
```

If you don't receive an empty result, the user likes your page.

If your App is a Page Tab App, you could also use the field "page" of the SignedRequest as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request/